# Delete INI section in Python

Tags: python, winapi, ini

In python, I'm using win32api to read and write INI settings as and when they are required into specific sections based on IDs.

Once I have finished with the section, I want to be able to delete the entire section from the INI file.  How would I go about doing this using the win32api python library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is to use native Python module for handling INI files [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html). Have you tried it already? It has remove_section method that probably will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Python specific answer, but look into calling [WritePrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `lpKeyName` parameter set to `NULL`. With this parameter set to `NULL` the entire section named in `lpAppName`, including all entries within the section, is deleted.